# Azure B2C - User Management (CRUD) - Single Tenant vs Multiple Tenants

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

For CRUD operations against graph api we have had to give several development teams application credentials. These teams are responsible for different apps and so far, we manage different Azure B2C tenants for each app. We want to consolidate into one B2C tenant for all apps.

What is the best way to do this and are there any concerns from doing so? Here are a few we have thought of

1. Giving tenant-wide permissions like Directory.ReadWrite.All and User.ReadWrite.All can cause a developer from one team inadvertently deleting identities of other teams.
2. Modification of attributes already in use by other apps for one app

Comment: What do you mean by "consolidate into one B2C tenant for all apps" and "attributes already in use by other apps for one app"? Please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks Allen
"consolidate into one B2C tenant for all apps" - Use one B2C tenant to handle authentication for all apps

Comment: "attributes already in use by other apps for one app" - One app X calls Graph API to modify an existing attribute A for a user. Same Attribute A is being used by another app Y and this change in value by X will now have an impact on how Y functions.

Comment: As far as I know, Azure AD does not have a ready-made solution to meet your needs. In your case, each team will be able to manage all the users in the one B2C tenant. My suggestion is controlling the permission with your own logic. For example, a user from group A has a group claim in id token which tells you he's from which group. Then when he calls MS graph to modify a user, check the user is from which group. If the user he is trying to modify is from group A, you allow it. Through this method, you can implement an admin from group A can only modify the users from the group A.

Comment: Moved the comment to answer so that this issue can be treated as answered for others' reference. If it's helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Azure AD does not have a ready-made solution to meet your needs.

In your case, each team will be able to manage all the users in the one B2C tenant. My suggestion is controlling the permission with your own logic.

For example, a user from group A has a group claim in id token which tells you he's from which group. Then when he calls MS graph to modify a user, check the user is from which group. If the user he is trying to modify is from group A, you allow it. Through this method, you can implement an admin from group A can only modify the users from the group A.

You can also use Group claim to implement the same thing.

References:

[How to: Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)

[Configure the Azure AD Application Registration for group attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes)